# How to change a value in xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, utf-8

I have the following xml file. The value from pathToFile can be empty in the xml file at start if you want. You can even delet pathToFile. Only the desired output and the generationDateLocal does matter.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<document>
  <properties>
    <basic>

      <property id="pathToFile">
        <value>\\srv\DATEN\generationDateLocal.pdf</value>
      <property id="generationDateLocal">
        <value>20170131T160139</value>
      </property>

    </basic>
  </properties>
</document>
```

The following output is desired.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<document>
  <properties>
    <basic>

      <property id="pathToFile">
        <value>\\srv\DATEN\20170131T160139.pdf</value>
      <property id="generationDateLocal">
        <value>20170131T160139</value>
      </property>

    </basic>
  </properties>
</document>
```

How can I achive this goal with using xslt?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="basic">
  <basic>
    <property id="pathToFile">
        <value>\\srv\DATEN\<xsl:value-of select="property[2]/value"/>.pdf</value>
    </property>
    <xsl:copy-of select="property[2]"/>
  </basic>
</xsl:template>
```